# why is this dot not greedy?

Tags: javascript, regex

I do not understand why the `.` in this regex does not greedily match the entire string:

```
var re = /.+b/g,
    st = "aaaaaabcd";

console.log( st.match(re) ); //["aaaaaab"]
```

http://jsbin.com/UmOraTI/1/edit?js,output

I've been trying to learn about greediness, it seems like `.+` should match **all** of the characters since `.` matches basically everything. It's the same with `*`. Can someone explain this?

Comment: so it does... you are trying to find all characters to `b` letter... and it did find it.

Comment: wouldn't that regex match any string of characters followed by a b?

Answer (score 7):

The `.+` can match the entire string, but then the `b` that follows it would have nothing to match. Greedy matching means that it will match as much as possible while still making it possible for the pattern that comes after it to successfully match.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the `.+` sure *is* being greedy... you just don't *see* it!

The regex engine will match all the characters up to `d` in the string, and once there, looks for `b`, but it's nowhere to be found.

Hence it goes back one character (called backtracking) and is now between `c` and `d` and again tries to match `b`, but no success (`d` is in front, not `b`).

It backtracks again to get between `b` and `c` but fails again.

It backtracks once more and gets in between `a` and `b` and finally matches! That's where it stops backtracking and returns the result you see.

This is why you get:

```
var re = /.+b/g,
    st = "aaaaaabcdbaa";

console.log( st.match(re) ); //["aaaaaabcdb"]
```

It backtracked after the last 2 `a`s and matched at the *last* `b`.

This is greediness!

Conversely....

```
var re = /.+?b/g,
    st = "aaaaaabcdbaa";

console.log( st.match(re) ); //["aaaaaab"]
```

This is laziness.

Some engines have operators to prevent this backtracking and this process can often make the regex be awfully slow; imagine having to backtrack many times in a single string (one which has a lot of `.*` usually).

Comment: So using the `?` is all about whether you want to capture the first instance of the next character in the regex or the last?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in a way, it *does* match the whole string.  Your regex matcher does something called **backtracking**, which causes it to back up until it finds an appropriate match.  So with your expression:

```
/.+b/
```

The match goes something like this:

```
    aaaaaabcd
.+  ---------
b            x
```

Then it discovers that it can't match the be, so the `.+` term "gives up" one of its matches, and the mather tries again:

```
    aaaaaabcd
.+  --------
b           x
```

Still no match, so it gives up another, (which won't help), and another, until it gets to this state:

```
    aaaaaabcd
.+  ------
b         -
```

Which is the longest match of your regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /<tr>.*<\/tr>/g,
    st = "<tr>asdf</tr>blah<tr>asdf</tr>";

console.log( st.match(re) );
```

You have to be careful with greedy mathes in regex.  The above example with still match the entire string.  Taken from your jsbin.